# Is it safe to use MediaStreamSample Processed event to get the status of a sample?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, uwp

I'm using MediaStreamSample class to create audio samples when playing backaudio in a Windows UWP application.

When playing back the recorded audio I handle the Processed event and update the playback position when this is fired.  Is it safe to use this to update the playback position? Or is will the position and audio become out of sync?

Below is a very brief sample of code that I used.

```
audioSample = MediaStreamSample.CreateFromBuffer(_sampleBuffer, _sampleTimespan);
audioSample.Duration = _timeSpan;
audioSample.KeyFrame = true;
audioSample.Processed += AudioSample_Processed;

private void AudioSample_Processed(MediaStreamSample sender, object args)
{
    //send notification to UI to show progress
}
```

Any suggestions on this would help. 
Thanks in advance.